# rational and Gaussian double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods, improper-integrals, multiple-integral

I am trying to calculate the following integral. When changing it to polar, then it becomes very ugly. Can one please at least show that it exists or not? I will also be very thankful for a plain evaluation! Hints are always nice of course!
$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{xy}{x^2-xy+1}\exp\left(-2x^2+6xy-6y^2\right)\, dx\, dy$$

Many thanks :-)

Comment: Before changing to polar coordinates, you should apply a suitable linear transform to turn the exponent to $-u^2-v^2$ (by reducing the conic). But the other factor in front will remain an ugly ratio of two quadratic expressions.

Comment: By the way, this is an improper integral as the denominator cancels along an hyperbola.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints, I will rotate the xy-plane to see how things change, mabe it becomes nicer. :-)

Comment: A rotation won't suffice. You need an anisotropic transform. And no, it won't become nice.

Comment: the rotation doesn't make it nice :-/ yo uare right!

Comment: I suggested [tag:improper-integrals] for this post; I hope that is appropriate even though it is a [tag:multiple-integral] $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Thank you :-)